# How do we add Share To... functionality for Tridion meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

We have the ability to share `main` and `meta` Questions or Answers.

The main Tridion StackExchange site also has "share to" options for:

- Google+
- Facebook
- Twitter

How can we qualify for or request these buttons for the Meta site?

I was specifically looking to Tweet [this question](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/137/46) on promoting the site; I can of course copy and paste in the meantime. :-)

Comment: This is now implemented, if you didn't see the status-completed tag. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked 5 other meta sites (for non-beta stack exchange sites) and the only one with had a share box allowing direct sharing to Google+, Facebook and Twitter was [meta stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

[image: meta stackoverflow share dialog]

meta stackoverflow is a 'special' meta site so this makes me think the type of sharing you are requesting might not be available on the meta SE sites. However, I think the best think to do is to probably flag this post as needs moderator attention so one of the SE community devs can chime in.

Comment: Thanks for looking around, flagged the question asking about it. Not a big deal if it's only for the main site.

Answer (score 4):

This is how all the child metas are set up (with the exception of [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)). There's no 'setting' to enable it, so it would need a systemic change to make that happen.

I checked into why it was set up this way, and best I can gather is it's because the child meta posts are generally more geared towards people who are actively using the site. That makes it awkward to share this stuff broadly across the broader Internet, especially given that new visitors can't even meaningfully interact with a child meta.

But I don't particularly agree with the distinction —

We shouldn't assume that someone's audience, motivation, or need for sharing is wrong for *this* site. Bigger picture, folks become accustomed to how these tools should work, and when they don't  work the way you'd expect, it makes for an unhappy, head-scratching experience. This isn't exactly a game-changing problem, but adding such exceptions in behavior between meta and the main Q&A should have a much greater impetus before justifying the inconsistency. I'm going to leave this a [feature-request](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's not critical, but I'd appreciate the feature. I think discussions and points about a Q&A community can be as compelling as the questions themselves. Who wouldn't want to check out "Who will moderate?" or "Pick a logo!" on their favorite SE site.